# Вывод stdout из paramiko неверно переносит строки

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

Пытаюсь получить список файлов с определенным расширением на удаленном компьютере
Однако при считывании не все пути до файлов корректно отображаются

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=secret, port=port)
cmd = '''dir /s /b /n D:\\*.bat\n'''
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd, get_pty=True)
for line in stdout:
    print(line)
```

Я получаю что-то вроде D:\dir\tes

t.bat

(т.е часть пути переносится на следующую строку)
пробовал считывать через read().decode(), через readlines(), результат тот же
можно как-нибудь решить проблему?

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас 3 варианта решения проблемы:

### 1

Откажитесь от `get_pty=True`.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
```

Если это неприемлемо для Windows, то переходим к следующему варианту.

### 2

Все-таки откажитесь от `get_pty=True`, но попробуйте получить PTY перед вызовом `exec_command`:

```
client.get_pty(term='xterm', width=200, height=24000)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
```

Главное здесь - увеличить ширину терминала. Ну и высоту тоже, чтобы избежать запросов на продолжение скроллинга - но с Windows командами с высотой проблем быть не должно.

Этот вариант я сам не пробовал, однако не вижу, почему бы ему не сработать. Если все же нет, то переходим к следующему варианту.

### 3

Можно использовать вариант ручного управления каналом:

```
client.connect(...)
channel = client.invoke_shell(term='xterm', width=200, height=24000)
channel.settimeout(30)
channel.send(cmd)
# получаем данные при помощи `channel.recv(len(channel.in_buffer)).decode('latin-1')`
# с дополнительными плясками по проверке, что команда-таки завершилась. 
# Я, например, отлавливал этот момент по появлению command prompt - регексом
channel.close()
```